# .mem and .wasm MIME type errors in Azure only

Tags: reactjs, azure, webassembly, mime, pdftron

This app was built in Visual Studio 2022 using the "ASP.NET Core with React.js" project template.  In a nutshell this template sets up a React front-end that lives in the same project with a .NET6 Web API backend.  A proxy config file defines routes that will be sent to the API, all others default to the React app.  It's a clever setup and is working well except for one recent problem.

When I run the app locally at localhost:3000 everything works flawlessly.

I created a publish profile in VS2022 to publish directly to Azure as an app service.  The publish is always successful.  I can browse the app in Azure and the React UI loads without issues.  There is one button in the app that triggers a 3rd party library called PDFTron to load an Excel file and preview it in the page.  Running locally this works perfectly.  Running in Azure I get a series of errors and the Excel preview never loads:

[image]

I'm using a 3rd party library called PDFTron for displaying an Excel file in the page.

Things I've tried:

PDFTron has an article listing the MIME types that need to be enabled.  Since I'm haivng no problem running locally I assume they're already enabled by default in my local VS2022 environment.  In azure I manually edited the published web.config as follows:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\DocuParseWebApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".xod" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".res" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".mem" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".wasm" mimeType="application/application/wasm" />
     </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Unfortunately this had no effect.

My Program.cs file:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html"); ;

app.Run();
```

Are there any additional steps to configure an App Service in Azure to work with these MIME types?

Comment: Most likely unrelated to the fact that MEM files are not loading, but it looks like your WASM type is wrong. Should just be "application/wasm" and not "application/application/wasm". See https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/faq/mime-types/#pdf-and-office.

Comment: "When I run the app locally at localhost:3000 everything works flawlessly." Note that by default Visual Studio launches 32bit IIS Express instance, which is Not the same as the Windows 64bit IIS server. As far as I have experienced they do Not share MIME settings. Perhaps you are setting the MIME for your 32bit IIS Express instance, but you need to actually also do this for your 64bit IIS instance, and that latter data is what Azure uses.